# Galaxy S plus does not see files on external SD

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I bought a 32Gb external SD for my S plus and can upload video files from the PC to the card. They show up on windows explorer as uploaded, but I cannot access them from the phone. The /mnt/sdcard folder shows the /external_sd folder as empty apart from a LOST.DIR folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried with any file explorer like es..

Comment: file explorer like es..? What is es..?

Comment: I mean any file explorer applications for ex: ES-file explorer in playstore

Comment: Downloaded ES-file explorer and it does not find any files in the external SD

Comment: Ooooh, after opening and closing the application it now sees all of the files! Thanks for your help.

Comment: it pleasure to help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think if your phone is 16 gb the max you can go with ext sd card is 16 gb
any bigger and the phone doesn't know what to do so 32 won't work
that's what they told me for my galaxy s2